# APNS Apple Push Service - message life span, gcm time_to_life counterpart

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, message, lifetime

i didn't found anything about a "lifespan" option for APNS messages. In Google Cloud Messaging we have it. See here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl

Can't imagine Apple don't provide it. Does someone know if it exists for Apple and give me a direction.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I might found something in the given link to gcm docs

"Currently, time_to_live is not supported for notification messages on iOS"

Can someone confirm this or is this just a gcm limitation.

Comment: Apple pushes have an expiry lifetime, if GCM doesn't support that and you need it then you could switch to Firebase - FCM which is the new version of GCM supports it.